# React remove column from table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here, I have created an application to add a number of row and column dynamically.

I want to remove created column on remove click, I tried many things but, nothing works for me.

When I added column remove button it also stops my row delete functionality.

Here my working example: (In this example I have given static value but, originally it has value given using user input )

Working code:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/kk0rn33wqr

```
//Remove column handler
onRemoveEvent = id => {
   alert(id);

   this.setState({
      //rowCount
    });
};


//Here created remove button
class Table extends Component {
  render() {
      let rowCount = this.props.rowCount;
      let numberOfColumn = this.props.numberOfColumn;
      return (
        <div id="Table">
          <table>
            <tr>{
                Array.from({length: numberOfColumn}).map((_, removeIdx) => (
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={() => this.onRemoveEvent(removeIdx)}>Remove</button>
                  </td>
                ))}
            </tr>

            {rowCount}
          </table>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: your ```<tr>``` tag seems to be out of place. I believe you said you want to build number of rows so shouldn't that be in a loop.

Comment: @philip_nunoo Sorry, i couldn't get you. have you checked my working example?

Comment: Your state.rowCount is sometimes a number and sometimes an array. I don't think that will work the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cobbled this together along the same lines as your code. I hope it's useful.

```js
function Thead({ n, handleColumn }) {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr.push(<td><button onClick={() => handleColumn(i)}>Remove</button></td>);
  }
  return <thead>{arr}</thead>;
}

function Row({ row, i, handleRow }) {
  return (
    <tr>
      {row.map(cell => <td>{cell}</td>)} 
      <td><button onClick={() => handleRow(i)}>x</button></td>
    </tr>
  )
}

class Table extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: props.data };
    this.handleColumn = this.handleColumn.bind(this);
    this.handleRow = this.handleRow.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleColumn(n) {
    const newData = this.state.data.map(row => {
      return row.filter((el, i) => i !== n);
    });
    this.setState({ data: newData });
  }
  
  handleRow(n) {
    const newData = this.state.data.filter((el, i) => i !== n);
    this.setState({ data: newData });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <Thead n={this.state.data[0].length} handleColumn={this.handleColumn} />
        <tbody>
          {this.state.data.map((row, i) => <Row row={row} i={i} handleRow={this.handleRow} />)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }

}

const data = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [2, 2, 3],
  [3, 2, 3]
]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried it in my App.js but, it won't allow me to remove row and column. https://jsfiddle.net/dn8aupgo/ (OfCourse not working in jsFiddle)

Comment: @ketan Just needed a tweak wrt to the way the table was being generated. [https://jsfiddle.net/635d4c9b/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/635d4c9b/1/)